# get pid of process - linux

Tags: linux, shell

I try to launch an app within it's path and get it's process id:

```
(cd /opt/server/TrackServer/release && ./TrackServer&) && echo $!
```

but I always get wrong PID.

Ie i get:

```
$ (cd /opt/server/TrackServer/release && ./TrackServer&) && echo $!
5078
$ ps aux | grep TrackServer
user    5250  0.6  0.0 153340  7824 pts/0    S    20:09   0:00 ./TrackServer
user    5253  0.0  0.0  14868   976 pts/0    S+   20:09   0:00 grep --color=auto TrackServer
```

how can I invoke the process within its path and get it's pid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's only one running, an easy way to do it is with `pidof TrackServer`

Answer (score 2):

`TrackServer` is a background process of the `(...)`-induced subshell, not your script, so `$!` in your script stores a different PID.

Try

```
pushd /opt/server/TrackServer/release && { ./TrackServer & echo $!; popd; }
```

Comment: you are right about the (...) but the one-liner propose is not working,

Comment: @WojciechSobczyk add a semicolon after _popd_ in the command above.

Comment: Sorry about the omitted semicolon; fixed.